# htmx: onLoad: "on full page load" and "on after swap"

Tags: javascript, htmx

I would like to initialize a `select` element like in the [tom-select Example](https://tom-select.js.org/examples/) with my own method:

```
<select id="select-repo" placeholder="Pick a repository..." multiple></select>
```

```
function my_select_init(el) {
  new TomSelect(el, {
    persist: false,
    createOnBlur: true,
    create: true
  })
}
```

There two different ways:

## Case 1: The full page gets loaded

In this case you can use one of the modern onLoad methods.

For example:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // do something here ...
}, false);
```

## Case 2: the fragment get inserted into the DOM via htmx

How to initialize the snippet?

## Preferred solution

I want the HTML and the on-load code to be in one place ([Locality of Behaviour](https://htmx.org/essays/locality-of-behaviour/)) and I want this html fragment to be the same for both cases.

Up to now I don't use Hyperscript or Alpine.js, but I am open to use one of these libraries, if this makes the solution simpler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to use is the `htmx.onLoad` callback:

```js
  htmx.onLoad(function(elt) {
    // look up all elements with the tomselect class on it within the element
    var allSelects = htmx.findAll(elt, ".tomselect")
    for( select of allSelects ) {
      new TomSelect(select, {
                    persist: false,
                    createOnBlur: true,
                    create: true
                   });
    }
  })
```

This javascript will execute initially when the page is loaded on the `body` element, and then for all new content added by htmx to the page.

See https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party