# JavaScript not functioning after htmx get/post request swapped

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, htmx

I'm building a **Django** project and trying to get and post data using **htmx** and everything works, which means I can get and post data there is no problem with that, but the problem is after data is **swapped** the bootstrap dropdown or tooltips or other **elements that need some javascript to function** including **jQuery carousel** is no longer working, I think the error is because after htmx swapped there is always new data added or replaced to the DOM, so the new data is no longer supported to any script.

so how can I handle this?

### Update:

One solution that comes to my mind is to force the browser to **re-load(re-download)** scripts without a page refresh, but I have no idea how can I implement this, please help!

Comment: You have to apply the 3rd party JS functions on the new elements after the HTMX swap. Have you read the [3rd Party JavaScript](https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party) section in the documentation? There's an example how to do it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [onLoad](https://htmx.org/api/#onLoad)? Example SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988846/htmx-onload-on-full-page-load-and-on-after-swap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to reload your js source files.
What you need is `htmx.onLoad` callback.

check [here](https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party) for more information.

```
htmx.onLoad(function(content) {
    // reinitialize your bootstrap elements here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving the Bootstrap JS from the body to the head fixes the issue with Bootstrap 5.3 and HTMX 1.9.10.

After that `hx-target` with `body` doesn't kill the Bootstrap components anymore.

Answer (score -1):

can you try with don't extend {% extends 'base.html' %} in swapped form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).